# Is the cesaro sum any less valid than the formal sum? (And the arbitrary nature of mathematics.)

Tags: soft-question

The title basically says it all. I've just watched [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww) explaining (without any formal definitions) that the 'sum' of the natural numbers is equal to -1/12. Now, the more I read about mathematics the more it seems to be quite arbitrary - but then this isn't really a problem because from what I understand we are just playing with arbitrary rules.

The problem I have is that I think a lot of people feel naturally inclined to attach some real-world meaning to mathematics. I often see what seems to be sensationalist mathematics explained in layman's terms to provoke a feeling of 'mathematics broke reality!' or something like that.

I'm actually struggling to comprehend the idea of mathematics at the moment so my writing may not be entirely together but a representation of my current thoughts. I would appreciate some clarity - possibly to explain the notion of applying 'realness' to certain elements of mathematics over others.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It's tough and arguably ineffective to tackle such broad statements.

Comment: @Newb I'm basically confused by the video I linked. When we say 'sum' is there any reason why we can't interpret that as formal sum, cesaro sum, or some method of summation that I invent. Surely I could claim that the 'sum' of the natural numbers is anything I want if I choose my definition of sum. Is the video's argument valid, strictly speaking?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to understand something about mathematics, the way to start is to forgot about this video as quickly as possible. It's not that this video is wrong - it's neither wrong or right, it's a bunch of confusing non-arguments.

One of the achievements of modern mathematics is to provide a consistent foundation for reasoning about infinite sums and infinite quantities. Those foundations require a bit of an effort to learn, but once you learn them, they enable to you *formally* deal with questions such as "what is the sum of $1+2+3+\ldots$". Those foundation then show that there *are* different ways to interpret such an expression, and depending on the interpretation you get different results. That shouldn't be surprising - after all, $1+2+3+\ldots$ isn't really a sum - it isn't something you can compute by doing arithmetic - but rather an abstract *expression* that you first have to assign some meaning to before it makes sense to speak about it's value.

The video, OTOH, ignores all that, and uses essentially arbitrary and ad-hoc arguments to argue that the sum "is obviously" $-\frac{1}{12}$. That's not mathematics, that's just ildly playing with numbers.